# How can I connect 3 4K 60Hz displays to my MacBook Pro with a single USB-C cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb, monterey, 4k

I would like to connect 3 4K 60Hz [displays](https://support.hp.com/de-de/product/hp-envy-27s-27-inch-display/13673507/document/c05576889) to my [MacBook Pro (M1 Max)](https://www.apple.com/ch-de/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro/16%22-space-grau-10-core-cpu-32-core-gpu-1tb#) via a single USB-C cable that also charges the MacBook. I had a look at some USB-C hubs, but I only found hubs that either [only support 2 4K displays at 60Hz](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/i-tec-triple-4k-usb-c-dockingstation-usb-hub-16740247?gclid=Cj0KCQjw3eeXBhD7ARIsAHjssr_Mbq5S1GSKNiaLUMV8ZgsC3EHEgw_uNUCozdl5t-UFD7Nk0LNnbZsaAsk4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and one at 30Hz or are [only compatible for Windows](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/docking_thunderbolt-docks-(universal-cable-docks)/40b00135us?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)…

Any answers or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: Which **exact** Mac model?

Comment: I added it to the question :)

Comment: While that Mac supports three monitors getting it to use one cable may be difficult *unless* you have monitors that support "daisy-chaining" the monitors via DisplayPort cables. you plug one cable into the Mac and then to the first monitor and from the first to the second, etc. It *should* work but it is unclear if those monitors support that.

Comment: I can't seem to find an official piece of information on apple.com but I believe the MacBook Pro with M1 Max can only drive 2 displays per Thunderbolt Bus, meaning you would have to connect the 3rd one to a different Thunderbolt Port (or HDMI). A workaround might be a Dock with DisplayLink.